# pandas create column referencing itself

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in pandas but the values are calculated referencing the value in the cell above it. I have a column called returns and essentially the value should be return * value from the previous row.

Conceptually I think it should be something like this, but this doesn't work and I'm not sure how to get it.

```
df2['value'] = [100 if x == 0 else x * y for x, y in zip(df2['return'], df2['value'].shift(1))]
```

So, data looks like this:

```
return
0
0.99756466142691
0.99846199238689
1.004349336899
1.0018775199783
```

I want this:

```
return          value
0.0000000000    100.0000000000
0.9975646614    99.7564661427
0.9984619924    99.6030399383
1.0043493369    100.0362471152
1.0018775200    100.2240671677
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is with loop, because need previous value:

```
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row['return'] == 0:
        df2.loc[i, 'value'] = 100 
    else:
        df2.loc[i, 'value'] = df2.loc[i,'return']  * df2.loc[i-1, 'value'] 

print (df2)
     return       value
0  0.000000  100.000000
1  0.997565   99.756466
2  0.998462   99.603040
3  1.004349  100.036247
4  1.001878  100.224067
```

The iterative nature of the calculation where the inputs depend on results of previous steps complicates vectorization. You could perhaps use apply with a function that does the same calculation as the loop, but behind the scenes this would also be a loop.

Comment: Thanks! This works, thank you for the lesson using iterrows.

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is a cumulative product.  The challenge is how you've arrange the initial pieces.
***Note:*** this is a vectorized solution that does not require looping.

```
df['value'] = df['return'].add(df['return'].eq(0)).cumprod().mul(100)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.return.replace(0, 100).cumprod()
```